# Amplify error on push after latest update to CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Using AWS-VAULT with 4 profiles in my `~/.aws/config` file. 3 assume roles profiles and the main.

when running say, `amplify push`, I get an error as follows:

```
Failed to get profile: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of undefined
```

I've removed and re-added the credentials via aws-vault.

I've also tried removing aws-vault and running a credentials file with the profile name associated to the main profile in my /.aws folder.

When I do that, I get error:

```
Name: ResourceNotFoundException : Message: User pool ca-central-1_****** does not exist.
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue, sorted out by doing the following.

Under `Project Directory -> Amplify -> .config -> local-aws-info.json` profile name was defined as ABC whereas new profile I created did not match the name. Simple went to `~/Users/username/.aws/` and changed profile name in credentials and config file to match the project. Or you can do the other way around if profile is being used by multiple projects or define a new profile with matching name,

Answer (score 1):

On Windows

I had the same error running `amplify init` in the part when you need to choose the user

So, I went to C:\Users\my_user.aws and I verified that my user was set, my problem was that for some reason the user exists in the config file but not in the credentials file, I just edited the file and everything worked fine.

Comment: I was never using a credentials file until this error. I was using aws-vault to set the credentials. After unsetting the aws-vault i created the credentials file and that is what kicked the user pool does not exist error

Answer (score 0):

On my case, the issue started with amplify 9, It appears that from this version it stopped looking on the config file for the keys(aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token), when I moved the keys from ~/.aws/config to ~/.aws/credentials , it ran successfully.